# Get transaction by item account id

Tags: yodlee

Hi I am using rest api to access yodlee aggregation services. i am not able to search transaction by item account id. My rest query is as follows

```
parameters = {
'transactionSearchRequest.searchFilter.itemAcctId'=>itemId,
'cobSessionToken'=>cobSessionToken,
'userSessionToken'=>userSessionToken,
'transactionSearchRequest.containerType'=>con_name,
'transactionSearchRequest.lowerFetchLimit'=>0,
'transactionSearchRequest.resultRange.endNumber'=>500,
'transactionSearchRequest.higherFetchLimit'=>500,
'transactionSearchRequest.resultRange.startNumber'=>1,
'transactionSearchRequest.ignoreUserInput'=>'true',
'transactionSearchRequest.searchFilter.transactionSplitType.splitType'=>"A"
}
```

The response is always all the transactions for the user instead of transactions for a particular item account id. 
Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 2):

You are passing ItemId but the parameter passed should be ItemAccoutnId.

Difference between ItemId and ItemAccountId  -

when you link a site say "Citibank" then an itemId is created and then say you have a saving and a checking account under Citibank then both these accounts will have an unique identifier called itemAccountId.

Hence the transaction search takes itemAccountId as the parameter and will return transaction only for that account.

Please use below API to get ItemAccountId and pass it to the transaction Search.
 https://developer.yodlee.com/Aggregation_API/Aggregation_Services_Guide/Aggregation_REST_API_Reference/getItemSummaryForItem1